# Only arrays and iterables are allowed

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I can not retrieve the details of the address table on html page. I have an error: ERROR Error: "Error trying to diff '[Object Object]." Only arrays and iterables are allowed "
the console displays the items to be recovered but can not retrieve the page

[Console image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DI79m.jpg)

Service Adress

```
 adresses: Adresse [] = [];
  adresseSubject = new Subject<Adresse[]>();

  constructor() { }

  emitAdresse(){
    this.adresseSubject.next(this.adresses);
  }


  getAdresse(){
    firebase.database().ref('adresse/' + firebase.auth().currentUser.uid )
      .on('value', (data)=>{
        this.adresses = data.val() ? data.val() : [];
        console.log();
        this.emitAdresse();
      });
  }
```

Page ts

```
 adresses : Adresse[];
  adresseSubscription: Subscription;

  constructor(private adresseService: AdresseService,  private router: Router) {}

  ngOnInit(){
    this.adresseSubscription = this.adresseService.adresseSubject.subscribe(
      (adresses: Adresse[]) => {
        this.adresses = adresses;
      }
    );
    this.adresseService.getAdresse();
    this.adresseService.emitAdresse();
  }
```

html

```
 <ion-card *ngFor="let adresse of adresses; let i = index" (click)="onViewAdresse(i)">
        <ion-card-content>
            <ion-row>
                <ion-col size="9" >
                        <!--<ion-col size="9" (click)="goTo(adress)">-->
                    <div><b>{{adresse.prenom}} {{adresse.nom}} </b></div>
                    <div>{{adresse.commune}}</div>
                    <div>{{adresse.numeroF}}</div>

                </ion-col>
                <ion-col size="3">
                    <div class="color-edit"><b>Modifier</b></div>
                </ion-col>
              </ion-row>
          </ion-card-content>
      </ion-card>
```

thanks you

Comment: Well the error explains what actually is wrong. You are trying to iterate an object, which is not iterable.

Comment: Try to `console.log(data.val())`, the data retrieved by firebase. Is it an array?

Comment: it is an object, I wish to make it in table

Answer (score 1):

Initialize `adresses` with an empty array. `ngFor` works with array, until `adresse` is subscribed, `adresses` is undefined in your code.

Try like this :

```
adresses : Adresse[] = []
```

Comment: I always have the same mistake